# What are the USB requirements for using the Quest 2 via USB-C?

Tags: pc, meta-quest-2

Is possible to use a Quest 2 in a PC with a good USB-C to USB-C cable or the Oculus Link Cable, but what are the USB requirements when using it via USB?

The USB 3.0+ standard is very confusing so I don't understand what specific USB version it requires.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [official Link Cable webpage](https://www.oculus.com/accessories/oculus-link/):

> SIGNAL REQUIREMENTS
>
> USB 3.2 Gen 1 Signalling 5 Gbps USB 2 / Backwards-compatible
>
> POWER SUPPLY : 3A

And [compatibility](https://support.oculus.com/articles/headsets-and-accessories/oculus-link/oculus-link-compatibility):

> **Oculus Link requires a high-quality USB cable capable of supporting data and power**. You'll also want to make sure that the USB cable is at least 3 meters (10 feet) for an optimal and comfortable experience.

(emphasis mine)

> You can also use a third-party cable. While quality can vary across third-party cables, we've tested the Anker cable internally with good results.

(The [Anker's cable](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B01MZIPYPY/), I assume)

Looks like 5Gbps speed is crucial for Oculus Link to work, though delivering power seems to be not so important... actually, it's not even recommended, since...

[Oculus support](https://support.oculus.com/articles/headsets-and-accessories/oculus-accessories/charger-recommendation-with-quest-2/) says:

> To keep your Oculus Quest 2 or Quest in good working condition, you should only charge your headset with the charger that was included in the box. **You should also avoid charging your headset while it's in use.**

(emphasis mine)

However, every USB-C cable that is able to provide 5Gbps speed is also capable of providing power, so playing with Oculus Link would gradually damage Quest's battery, so keep that in your mind.

Sidenote: According to [this reddit's submission](https://www.reddit.com/r/oculus/comments/jgb4yr/oculus_link_test_speed_with_quest_2/)...

Most of reports shows that connection speed is ~3.0Gbps even with official Link cable, and they say that they're not facing any issue.

Some of users even having ~1.2Gbps speed, but they also aren't experiencing any issue, so... 5Gbps is not so crucial? Which is understandable, since videos doesn't take that much of data value.

FWIW, you can also use Wifi to use Oculus Link([Oculus Air Link](https://support.oculus.com/509273027107091)), and I suppose they aren't capable of transmitting stable 5Gbps data. Though, in my experience, I've had no issues even when playing Beat saber(which requires specific timing to play) with Oculus Air Link.

In conclusion... 1.0~2.5Gbps is sufficient. Power delivery is not so important, or rather, should be avoided.

Comment: Those are the specs for the Link Cable, but you can use any USB-C cable. There is also the USB Power Delivery requirements for charging.

Comment: @Lemon Well, there's much more info on that webpage, so... I guess I'd edit my answer to include it.

Comment: I don't know how or why, but the cable I use is rated for 480 Mbps and works just fine. The oculus program does complain and recommends a USB 3.0 cable. But it works! Though, am I missing out on some graphics? I don't know, the graphics are better than using airlink though

Comment: @AlexKristensen As I stated, videos doesn't take that much (over 1.0Gbps) of data, and controls also wouldn't. Naturally, most of videos nowadays are around 100 to 150Mbps, and it is already overkill. [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EOWsqgHgq6w) that I've took to answer a question asked here, is just only 25Mbps and it does seems to be as same as my raw experience. I do not know why Oculus/Meta is requiring 5.0Gbps, or even higher than 1.0Gbps. Stability, perhaps?

Comment: Do take a note that, as you said, even if it's 480Mbps, it is 100% better than Air Link, in terms of graphics and lag. Cables are a bit annoying when playing games though.